# Is there any OCR SDK for c++ builder?

Tags: ocr, c++builder, image-recognition, text-recognition

I'd like to add character recognition functionality to my application that's why asking you what's the best available and affordable OCR SDK . I looked at ABBY FineReader Engine 10.0 but haven't got trial version yet as I requested from the official site!

I've downloaded Asprise OCR SDK but it's doesn't recognize Cyrillic symbols..

How to implement character recognition on my application ? By using what kind of libs, SDKs, APIs and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's Cunieform and Google's Tesseract OCR, both of which are free. Personally I've used Tesseract, the SDK was giving a lot of trouble so finally decided to simply call the command line interface of Tesseract with arguments from within my C program using the `system()` function.

Lots of people face difficulties with the Tesseract installation, so here's a short summary (version 2 works for me, insert appropriate version if necessary):

1. Download the following from the svn: `tesseract-2.00.tar.gz`, `tesseract-2.00.exe6.tar.gz`, `tesseract-2.00.eng.tar.gz`
2. Unzip `tesseract-2.00.tar.gz` to a folder
3. Unzip `tesseract-2.00.exe6.tar.gz` and move to where `tesseract-2.00.tar.gz` was unzipped. A few files will be replaced this way
4. Similarly unzip `tesseract-2.00.eng.tar.gz` and move to `tesseract-2.00.tar.gz` where tessdata folder will be replaced.

   After all this is done, open the tesseract.dsw workspace, select All Files and do "Rebuild All." This'll take a while with loads of warnings but hopefully no errors.

   The command using DOS shell is `tesseract picture.tif textfile -l eng`. So basically save your image as a TIFF file, run the command from within your program and then read in the OCR output strings from the text file.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend you Crystal OCR if you don't need to recognize a very complex documents, they sent me C++ Builder sample by request. IMHO, Tesseract is still buggy, though it's the best free OCR of course.

Comment: Just downloaded it! I'll go try it!!!! Also could you please send me a working example in c++ builder that you've requested ! send to suhrob87  at gmail dot com; Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try KSAI-Toolkits. It has a completely ocr application, which include C++ API, OCR model, benchmark and test data. And it supports different platforms.